# Node express: i cannot get value of id from jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I cannot get the value of id sent from jQuery to node express

Code in jquery:

```
var datename = $("#date").val();
$.post("../../app.js",
    {
      datename: datename,

    },
    function(datename,status){
      alert("Data: " + datename + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

Code in express:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('../../functionscript.js', function(req, res) {
var date = req.body.datename;
 res.json({flag: true});
    console.log(date); 
    res.end(date);

});
```

After clicking to post console says: POST /app.js 404 5ms

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error defining your routes. The URL that `app.post` defines is the one that jquery/your browser should call:

```
app.post('/someurl')
```

and in jquery:

```
$.post('/someurl',
```

`app.js` is probably the name of your node.js application? You cannot use that name from the browser, your node.js application is only called using the routes defined with express.

Answer (score 1):

#### server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
 
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/getData', function(req, res){ // this is your route here
    var date = req.body.datename;
    res.send(200, date);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

#### on the client side

```
var datename = $("#date").val();
$.post('/getData', { // use the route here
    datename: datename
}, function (datename, status){
    alert("Data: " + datename + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```